# Управление локальной Active Directory из облака

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory, ldap

Начальство поставило задачу реализовать операции создания, редактирования и перемещения пользователей в локальной Active Directory из приложения asp.net, размещенного в Azure. Реально ли это сделать, и если да, то такими средствами? Можно ли обойтись без Azure Active Directory. Будут ли LDAP работать в облаке? Нужно ли настраивать что-то в локальной AD?

Comment: Мне кажется проблем быть не должно. В приложении же просто указываешь путь к LDAP и работаешь с ним. А Вы пробовали подключиться к своему LDAP из приложения?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya на локальной машине подключается, а из облака нет, не дает доступ. У меня просто есть подозрение, что Azure AD затем и сделана, что облачные сервисы больше никаким способом подключиться к AD не могут.

Comment: Зависит от того, как подключаетесь, должно работать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно. Azure AD для этого не нужен совсем. В AD тоже настраивать ничего не придется. Пользоваться можно будет обычными .NET библиотеками для доступа к LDAP (ну или Active Directory). Есть множество правильных и безопасных путей.

- Первый через виртуальную сеть и VPN.
- Второй это создание асинхронной, пассивной коммуникации с LDAP через Queue и сервис (даже не придется открывать порты в сетке).
- Третий это создание просто веб-сервиса который надо будет захостить в корпоративной сети и к которому будет обращаться UI. То бишь вся основноая бизнес логика должна быть в нём.
- Возможно, что можно устроить коммуникацию через Azure Hybrid Connection (BizTalk Services), но я не уверен, будет ли это работать с LDAP.

Опишу самый простой путь (с моей точки зрения):

1. Создаёте Azure Virtual Network с диапазоном адресов который не перекрещивается с адресами вашей коропоративной сети (опционально можете выбрать ваш DNS-Сервер для доступа к машинам по их имени, а не айпи)
2. Создаёте Loсal Network с диапазононом адресов вашей корпоративной сети и указываете ваш Public IP
3. Создаёте создаете VPN-Gateway в виртуальной сети (static routing как правило достаточно) [вот пример](https://techlib.barracuda.com/ngx/configazurevpngateway) или [вот видео про это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUj7oJyGRxU).
4. Подчлючаетесь с вашего Gateway из корпоратвной сети к VPN-Gateway в Azure
5. Создаете в Azure новый App Service (Azure Website) как минимум тарифного плана Standard
6. [Интегрируете ваш App в виртуальную сеть](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/)
7. Разрабатываете ваше приложение локально
8. Развертываете ваше приложение App Service
9. Вуаля, вы можете безопасно из вашего App'a получить доступ к Directory Service в вашей сети.

**UPDATE:**

По пути на работу мне пришла в голову мысль, что для поставленной задачи Azure Websites (App Serivces) уровня Standard, пожалуй, слишком дороговато. Возьмите лучше за место этого Azure Web Role уровня A0. Она стоит в разы дешевле и так же само её можно сконфигурировать для использования виртуальной сети.

**P.S.** Озученная в одном из ответов возможность реализовать это при помощи Azure AD исключается, ибо Azure AD и просто AD, это не освсем одно и то же. Включая синхрнизацию вы не получаете прямой доступ к AD, а получаете некую копию его аттрибутов в Azure AD. В Azure AD нет Organisational Units (OU's). Соответственно перемещать пользователей будет некуда и неоткуда. Максимум что вы сможете сделать это настроить изменение и обратную синнхронизацию некоторых AD-Аттрибутов. Вот [список аттрибутов которые синхронизируются в AAD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnectsync-attributes-synchronized/). "Writeback" (синхронизацию в обратном направлении) поддерживают лишь некоторые из них. К тому же Writeback на данное время (март 2016) находится всё ещё в Preview-фазе.

Comment: Вооот я по той же причине AAD исключаю, что перемещение между юнитами невозможно. Будем пробовать ваш вариант, спасибо за подробную инструкцию! :)

Comment: вот теперь убедили =)

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев: посмотрите, я небольшой апдейт в пост запилил. Вам пригодится.