# Access Denied при сбросе пароля

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-websites

Имеем код:

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com", "DC=domain,DC=com", "login", "password");
        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
        //устанавливаем новый пароль
        try {
            user.SetPassword(newPass);
```

При этом login - самый админский из всех возможных аккаунтов в Active Directory.
Запускаем это дело на localhost - все отлично. Пробуем запустить ту же процедуру на удаленном сервере, получаем ошибку:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

```
entry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] {newPass});
```

дает точно такой же результат. При этом, другие методы Invoke и UserPrincipal работают без проблем, ломается только SetPassword. Веб страница хостится на Azure Websites. В чем может быть проблема? Какая приложению разница, откуда работать?

Comment: Запускайте приложение под доменным админом

Comment: @Monk а в Azure и так можно? Как это сделать?

Comment: Не знаю. Суть в том, что вы хотите поменять кому то пароль. Менять пароли могут не все, а потому лучше выполнять приложение под тем пользователем, который это может делать.

Comment: @Monk так сейчас например пользователь создается и редактируется (а это тоже не все могут). Почему смена пароля требует каких-то особых привилегий?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы пытаетесь через страницу, которая хостится в Azure поменять пароль в локальной Active Directory? Я уже в принципе отвечал на этот вопрос вам же http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505041/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-active-directory-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0. Вы создали VPN тоннель и всё равно не получается?

Comment: @WalterNuss да, тоннель работает прекрасно, не работает только изменение пароля (почему - не понятно, остальные атрибуты редактируются без проблем)

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, странно. Подумаю вечерком на досуге над этой проблемой. Должно работать.

Comment: А какова вообще постановка задачи? Только админ должен менять пароли или сами пользователи могут делать для себя ресет? Если пользователи сами себе, то это может и ADFS: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samueld/2015/05/13/adfs-2012-r2-now-supports-password-change-not-reset-across-all-devices/ (который у вас, на сколько мне известно установлен).

Comment: @WalterNuss не, только админ. Юзерам проще пароль просрочить и они себе сами его поменяют при следующем входе. Да и сброс пароля обычным пользователям в принципе не безопасно давать

Comment: @WalterNuss да и при создании пользователя ему же обязательно нужно пароль установить

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, это может быть проблема с DCOM. Посмотрите документацию: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?tduid=%28432ee6911649b70fd77a01b918d1871f%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-NUv_28AEh4eeEGxQVtRSfw%29%28%29

Comment: Give the user Remote Launch and Remote Activation permissions in dcomcnfg. Right-click My Computer-> Properties. Under COM Security, click "Edit Limits" for both sections. Give the user you want remote access, remote launch, and remote activation. Then go to DCOM Config, find "Windows Management Instrumentation", and give the user you want Remote Launch and Remote Activation.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется проблема в том, что ASP.NET не авторизован для доступа к запрошенным ресурсам. По умолчанию в ASP для запросов используется пользователь по типу {MACHINE}\ASPNET. Для того, что бы обойти это, необходимо добавить в Web.config `<identity impersonate="true"/>`.

Comment: К сожалению, не получилось. Попробовал в identity явно указывать userName и Password - вообще их не принимает