# Как запустить App Service в Azure от имени доменного пользователя?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-websites

В профиле публикации Azure App Service есть такие параметры:

```
userName="$имяприложения"
userPWD="какойтооченьдлинныйнеизвестныйпароль"
```

Может их нужно поменять? Как и на что? Зачем доллар перед логином? Откуда взялся этот пароль? Я его таким не устанавливал. Возможно ли запустить App Service в Azure от имени доменного пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом профиле публикации указан пользователь для деплоймента. Генерируется он и пароль самой платтформой Azure. Почему там стоит доллар и прочее - тайна покрытая мраком. Известна она, наверняка лишь разработчикам платтформы. Есть некоторые догадки почему это так, но не более того.

Если ты соберешься деплоить твоё приложение к примеру через FTP или TFS, да и даже просто из Visual Studio, то с тебя и спросят этот пароль и пользователя.

Поменять при необходимости можно через портал (portal.azure.com), но просто так менять его не вижу смысла.

В заголовке вопроса стоит: "Как запустить App Service в Azure от имени доменного пользователя?" Вам это реально жизненно необходимо? Если я не ошибаюсь, то именно запустить App Service никак вообще. Это PaaS (Plattform as a Service) и вы управляете там лишь вашим приложением, а не целой IIS-фермой. [Вот тут вот](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Deep-Dive/01) ребята с 51й минуты рассказывают про то как устроены App Services.

Comment: Проблема вытекла из этого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518087/access-denied-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment635422_518087